# Got error when try to sync sharepoint tasks with exchange/outlook 2013

Tags: tasks, sync, exchange

I am using sp2013 onpremise standard licence. I have created a project site. Inside this project site I have a tasks list. I try to sync the tasks list with exchange/Outlook 2013.

But I got this error:

> We weren't able to start syncing your tasks because one or more
>   pre-requisites for connecting to Exchange server could not be found.
>   Please contact your administrator to resolve this issue.

[image]

This farm feature is activated:

> Farm Level Exchange Tasks Sync

I have already this service application created:

> Work management service application

I have installed the "ExchangeWebServices" API on my app server:

```
msiexec /i EwsManagedApi.msi addlocal="ExchangeWebServicesApi_Feature,ExchangeWebServicesApi_Gac"
```

I have configured User Profile Synchronization and it is scheduled every day.

I do **NOT** yet run this script on the exchange 2013 server:

```
.\Configure-EnterprisePartnerApplication.ps1 -ApplicationType Sharepoint -AuthMetadataUrl https://<SP_FQDN>/_layouts/15/metadata/json/1
```

My webapplication is an intranet and dont have ssl. I have only an http url. Is it possible to get this sync worked on an http webapplication?

Comment: Could you translate the error message? Im not so good at understanding dutch..

Comment: the error is already translated. See above the printscreen: We weren't able to start syncing your tasks because one or more pre-requisites for connecting to Exchange server could not be found. Please contact your administrator to resolve this issue.

Comment: I see, thanks. Have you checked your ULS logs when you are trying to the synchronization?

Comment: I need first run this script on the exchange server(.\Configure-EnterprisePartnerApplication.ps1 and the rest...). I didnt yet let it do by a collegea. But I dont have an ssl webapplication. Is it also possible without ssl?

Comment: Have you read this article? It states that SharePoint Server and Exchange Server must be installed in the same environment for task lists to be able to sync correctly. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2876938

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the below steps are performed.

- You will need to have Exchange 2013 in your environment.
- You will also need to install Exchange 2013 Web Services Managed API 2.0
- Establish an OAuth trust on the Exchange Server

read more about the pre-req on this technet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554516.aspx

Comment: I am stuck on this requirement: Establish an OAuth trust on the Exchange Server. Is an SSL realy required? Without SSL not possible?

Comment: I have added an certifacate, add https binding in iis, add new AAM https url. Now the exchange commando is working.

Answer (score 0):

Sync Outlook With Your SharePoint Task List

1. Go to your SharePoint site.
2. Click on the desired task / find the task list in the View All Site Content pane.
3. Click on the List tab.
4. Click Connect & Export then Open in Outlook.
5. Click OK.